# Hadoop 2.2.0 source code packaging

Tags: java, hadoop, maven-3

My Aim is "To make changes in scheduling of Hadoop 2.2.0 ". For importing hadoop src code and compile it i followed [this link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment).
command given in that link was successfully done om my ubuntu 12.4. After making changes now i want to package it(According to maven).

I followed this command: "mvn package -Pdist,native,docs -DskipTests -Dtar"
but i am getting following error:

*[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin' from the repositories [local (/home/pict/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException*

According to error i think  "given plugin is not in local repository". But i searched manually in given location... it is available there. Then what may be the problem.....?

Please help me to resolve this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the point......... i haven't built(compiled) native library and in command

"mvn package -Pdist,native,docs -DskipTests -Dtar" i am saying to package it.

It is not necessary to build(compile) native libraries by your own. So there is command to package source code without native library and documentation i.e
"mvn package -Pdist -DskipTests -Dtar" which ran successfully without errors.

With this command we can create "hadoop distribution" from source code